# How to create a keyboard shortcut for comboboxes in UWP

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

I have a list of 50 or so items in a combobox and I want to provide a keyboard shortcut functionality similar to what was available in Windows 7 so that the user can type in a shortcut and it will quickly jump to the value they want. Is there a way to do this other than to create a keypress event?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: You can use [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396). But it's similar to keypress event. Otherwise, I can't figure out a way to do that.